# How to solve the CORS issue in ajax function without use of json

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, cors

I have an ajax function like:

```
function fn_nextitem(sliderNo){
    
  $.get("/index.php?op=ajax", {slide_no:sliderNo},function(resp) {
    if (resp) {
     
     
      $('#Div').append(resp);
    }
   else {
  
   } 
}
```

My php code is like:

```
if(!empty($items )){  
          foreach ($items as $itemid => $info) ;
            $html = include(TEMPLATE_PATH . "/list.php");
          endforeach; 
    
  }
```

This function is working fine in my local system. But after I moved this file to the test server, then I got the CORS error. I searching how to solve this issue and found- to add jsonp in the ajax function. But I couldn't add this, because I want to append a template or page in my ajax function success. Is there any option to solve this issue without using JSON? If I use the json then I didnt get my desired result.

Comment: So your PHP code is on a different domain than the clientside code? It is unclear how a relative url would cause CORS problem.

Comment: Do you need to solve it for development purposes or for production?

Comment: No, my client-side and server-side code are in the same domain

Comment: I don't know how it happens? Its working in my local dev.

Comment: Well is the request redirecting? Something is off, what do you see in the network request.

Comment: I saw the CORS error in the network.

Comment: So what did you see with the network request? What was in the response. You need to debug it.

Comment: After I got the CORS error, then my response is failed to load data.

Comment: WHAT IS IN THE NETWORK PANEL IN THE DEVELOPER TOOLS. Use the developer tools to look at the request. Did it go to the correct url? Did it redirect? What is in the response?

Comment: I am using the developer tools. I got the correct URL with the status CORS error and its type is xhr. My response is failed to load response data. No data was found for resources with a given identifier.

Comment: I am not sure how the network panel on the developer tools would have a CORS error listed....Makes me wonder if you are looking at the right spot.

Comment: I got the result when I add this 2 line header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");

Answer (score 0):

You should handle CORS at  Server side. Which server ?

NGINX

OR

APACHE.

OR, you can handle it with PHP or programming language that you are using. Your server programming language (such as php, java or nodejs  can work on headers then replace. )

Here is the Root solution if you are using PLESK .  Please write what your are using as web server.  ?

1. Warning: Only one header Access-Control-Allow-Origin can be added.
2. CORS will not work if the header is defined both in nginx and Apache, or twice for Apache or nginx respectively.
3. Log in to Plesk on the server where the domain example.com is hosted.
4. GO TO ->  Apache & nginx Settings.

**Add the CORS header:**

```
for Apache:
  Add the following line to the field Additional directives for 
   HTTP:
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://stack....org"
   Add the following line to the field Additional directives for       
   HTTPS:
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://stack...org"


    for nginx:
    Add one of the following lines to the field Additional nginx 
    directives, depending on whether website works via HTTP or HTTPS:

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://stack...org';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://stack..org';
```

Click OK or Apply at the bottom of the page to apply the changes.

For example,  For PHP  you can use such a script.

```
 <?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```

Comment: I am using APACHE

Comment: @Sonia you can try the php 2 line codes that i had been written.    header(".....") ....  Just test it, if not ok,  change HEADER at plesk side for apache.

Comment: Unsure why OP would need CORS set when it is the same domain.

Comment: @epascarello may be The person using differen machine to test and posting or receiving data from another server. this can happen. We do not have log files.

Comment: How does a relative URL hit a different server?

Comment: @KUTAY Yes. I am working in my local dev. At that time, there is no issue. After I  moved to git server then I got the CORS error.

Comment: @epascarello  JS application based on reverse proxy based over gateway redirection.  . I got the same problem before.  But I do not know, The person works with reverse proxies ... May be has different error.

Comment: @KUTAYZORLU Yes, It's working for me. I just add 2 PHP lines with header()  to the above my PHP codes.

Answer (score -1):

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
    
if(!empty($items )){  
  foreach ($items as $itemid => $info) ;
     $html = include(TEMPLATE_PATH . "/list.php");
  endforeach; 
        
}
```